# The python command starts the the wrong version of the python interpreter

Tags: python, python3

I am using Mac OS X Version 10.13.1 and I have just installed anaconda.  I have created a virtual environment using the command

```
conda create -n py3 python=3
```

Then, I have started the python interpreter using the command

```
python
```

To my surprise, the preinstalled python 2.7 from /usr/bin showed up instead of python 3.6.  In order to check what is going wrong I issued the command

```
which python
```

The result was even more surprising,  I got the following:

```
/Users/karlstroetmann/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/python
```

When I then invoked the command

```
/Users/karldrstroetmann/anaconda2/envs/py3/bin/python
```

I did get python 3.6.3.  But I don't understand why I cannot invoke this version by just typping `python`.  What am I missing here? Any hints would be very much appreciated.

Comment: `hash -t python`? Then try `hash -r` if it doesn't match & see.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's very likely that the `python` command has been [hashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_(Unix)) and that you need to clear the cache. In order to see what executable is actually being run you can use the `type` command, e.g.:

```bsh
type -a python
```

Unlike the `which` command, the `type` command is aware of hashed programs, as well as aliases and shell functions.

For further discussion of which (no pun intended) commands to use to determine which programs are executed by the shell, see the following post:

- [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Alternatively, you can also use the `hash` command itself to determine if a given command has been hashed, e.g:

```bsh
hash -t python
```

You can also list all hashed commands by running `hash` without any arguments, i.e.:

```bsh
hash
```

Similarly, you can use the `alias` command to check if a given command is an alias, e.g.:

```bsh
alias python
```

And you can list all active aliases as well:

```bsh
alias
```

To clear the cached Python program you can use the following command:

```bsh
hash -d python
```

Alternatively, you can clear everything all at once:

```bsh
hash -r
```

To clear a single alias you could use the `unalias` command, e.g.:

```bsh
unalias python
```

Or you could clear all aliases at once:

```bsh
unalias -a
```

Comment: Maaan... for a linux newbie... this wasted a good couple of ours of my time...
> installs python > python --version > WRONG version > which python > THIS/python > THIS/python --version > correct version... Turns out it was hashed... :(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem, it was a stupid mistake: I had an alias for python in my .bashrc.  I had forgotten about this alias and hence the problem resulted.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you invoked your virtual env from the anaconda (base) environment.  Use `conda deactivate` to exit out of *all* anaconda environments, then `conda activate <myenv>` to get back to your env.

That worked for me anyway.  Found it in a StackExchange thread.