# How do I control which command is when i type python in the shell

Tags: python, which

I use anaconda as a way to handle virtual environments. This means I have multiple version of python installed. I experience that the wrong python version starts when I run python from the shell.

Running

```
Which python
/anaconda3/envs/dash-two/bin/python
```

```
type -a python
 python is /anaconda3/envs/dash-two/bin/python
 python is /usr/bin/python
```

Inspired by this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/403972/336872) I have tried hash -t python
and looked at the output of alias

Comment: Which is the "right" and which is the "wrong" python `/anaconda3/envs/dash-two/bin/python` or `/usr/bin/python`?

Comment: I want /anaconda3/envs/dash-two/bin/python

Comment: I solved the problem:

My .bash_profile script had these two lines:
`export PATH="$PATH:~/bin"`
`export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"`

When calling .bash_profile more than once it would keep adding to the path.
The built in terminal in VS Code copies you path and runs the the .bash_profile script so starting it has the same effect as running .bash_profile twice. 

The problem was that all since all lines referred to the old $PATH variable it would just keep growing. 

Adding this `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin` at the start solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled in the "PATH" environment variable.

PATH is a list of directories to search in order for the command you've typed.  It's a single string seperated by colons.  Eg: anything I've placed in my home directory (`/home/philip/bin`) will be used instead of anything in `/usr/bin/` because my PATH is set to:

```
echo $PATH
/home/philip/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

To temporarily change your path you can set it with "export".  Eg:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/philip/bin
```

To set this permanently you will need to set it in your profile.  This can be done by putting a line similar to the one above (with your re-ordered path) into a file in your home directory called `.profile`.  If that doesn't exist, just created it and add the line.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to use virtual environments but have not activated one. To do that (assuming you have the basic venv stuff installed — works better for python3)

```
$ mkdir pytry
$ python3 -m virtualenv pytry
```

Now you should have a virtual env directory in `pytry`. cd into `pytry` and you should see for example

```
$ ls
bin  include  lib  local  share
$
```

Now run

```
source bin/activate
```

Note run above from the virtual env directory (in our case `pytry`)

Now you should find that your prompt should have changed from (say) `$` to `(pytry) $`

And `which python` will tell you your python executable

If you want a different executable then at the time of creation of the venv you need to run instead of

```
python3 -m virtualenv pytry
```

do

```
python3 -m virtualenv -p other_python_executable pytry
```

In general this will show help

```
$ python3 -m virtualenv -h
```

Comment: It may be that they have an `activate` script in their `/anaconda3/envs/dash-two/bin` directory?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Anaconda is stomping on your PATH (i.e. promoting the path of its own python interpreter in front of the path to the default system interpreter). There are a couple of ways to deal with this:

1. Create the Anaconda instance with the correct version of python:

   ```
   conda create -n myenv python=3.4
   ```
2. Override the PATH environment variable once you've loaded the anaconda instance.

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Or place the preferred path in the first line of the script file, set the the file as executable and run it as a shell script. The first line of the script would look something like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   ```

   You would set the file executable with the 'chmod' command:

   ```
   > chmod 700 file.py
   ```

   Then run from the command line as:

   ```
   > file.py
   ```